# REST sub-entities

Tags: node.js, rest, routes, restful-url

What is the proper, RESTful, URL structure for updating sub-entities?

For instance, I have a Question entity. A Question can have many Answers. Answers are more than just a string, they have a user, pubDate etc.

The URL for creating a Question entity is like so:

```
/questions/create
```

What would the proper format be for creating an answer to a specific question? Maybe something like:

```
/questions/{questionId}/answers/create
```

Or should they have their own dedicated route, like:

```
/answers/create?questionId={questionId}
```

Thanks for any help you guys can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to common belief, REST isn't really about URL structure.  In fact, there should be only one 'human-readable' URL, all the rest are discovered by HATEOAS.

Also, there shouldn't be any "URL for creating a Question".  There should be one (or many) question containers, and when you POST there, new entities are created.  Similarly, once you have the Question URL (returned when created, the client shouldn't know what 'structure' it has), you do new POSTs there to create answers.

In your example, once you do any required autentication, a GET to the 'root' URL could return a 'main' resource with all needed containers:

```
GET /api/
=> { "questions":"/api/questions/", .... }

GET /api/questions/
=> [{"name":"firstone", "href":"/api/questions/11"}, 
    {"name":"final", "href":"/api/questions/43"}]

GET /api/questions/101
=> {
    "name":"firstone", 
    "href":"/api/questions/11", 
    "text":"2+2", 
    "answers":[
        {"key":"A", "text":"23", "href":"/api/answers/15"},
        {"key":"B", "text":"3", "href":"/api/answers/34"},
        {"key":"C", "text":"4", "href":"/api/answers/7"}
    ]
}
```

to add a new question:

```
POST /api/questions/   {"name":"onemore", "text":"2^2"}
=> 201 Location: /api/questions/45   
data: {"name":"onemore", "text":"2^2", "href":"/api/questions/45"}

GET /api/questions/45
=> {"name":"onemore", "text":"2^2", "href":"/api/questions/45"}
```

to add an answer:

```
POST /api/questions/45    {"key":"A", "text":"4.5"}
=> 201 Location: /api/answers/56
data: {"key":"A", "text":"4.5", "href":"/api/answers/56", "question":"/api/questions/45"}
```

to modify the answer's text:

```
PUT /api/answers/56   {"key":"A", "text":"4.8"}
=> 200
data: {"key":"A", "text":"4.5", "href":"/api/answers/56", "question":"/api/questions/45"}
```

Of course, there are many variations on this, especially about how much 'deep' information is returned when you GET a container.  In this example, when you GET a question, there's a list of answers.  On one extreme, it could be just a list of URLs and the client must get each one, on the other extreme it could be the whole data for each one, so you have everything you need with a single request.

Typically, you have to pick a balance for each container, there might be some 'basic' fields that are good to have from the first request, while others can be delayed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using HTTP Verbs. So you're suggesting I POST to a /questions/{questionId} to create an Answer for a question? That doesn't seem very expressive to me, but maybe I'm missing the point of REST? Would that be preferable to using a PUT to *update* the question with an answer? ** I posted this before you updated your answer, let me have a read and see if it answers my question

Comment: Great, thanks for going into more detail. I'm still not entirely convinced a POST to /api/questions/45 is a very expressive way of creating an Answer. For instance, what if there were more than one subentity that could be created on a Question?

Comment: don't think too much on the URLs, think on resources.  some resources are containers, to create a new resource, you POST to a container, the server responds with the new URL.  to update an existing resource you PUT to it's URL.  If a question can have more than one kind of related entities, maybe it shouldn't be a container itself, but when you GET it, you find the containers URLs.  something like `GET /api/questions/101 => {...., "answers":"/api/questions/101/answers/", "hints":"/api/questions/101/hints/", ....}` then you can POST to the `answers` container to add a new one.